# Delete and add values to enum .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, enums

I've searched a lot but couldn't find how to delete and add values from/to enum in .NET

Let's say we have enum like this:

```
Public Enum Coordinates
x
y
z
End Enum
```

What I need is the enum to become like this:

```
Public Enum Coordinates
x
y
End Enum
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for `Dictionary<K, T>`?

Comment: you can't modify an Enum during runtime. It is a list defined in code and should only be used if this list doesn't have to be changed by the user.

Comment: It is not possible (and not the intend) to modify Enumerations at runtime, you should definitly use the correct data structure for this. E.g. like Dimitry suggested an `Dictionary<Key, Value>`

Comment: You can't do that without recompiling.

Comment: Could you explain further what you are trying to achieve? Modifying enum declaration during run-time is not possible.

Comment: Why in the world do you need to modify an Enum run time?

Comment: You don't mention that you need this at *run time* - just delete the `z` line in the editor... ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible (and not the intend) to modify Enumerations at runtime, you should definitly use the correct data structure for this. E.g. like Dimitry suggested an `Dictionary<Key, Value>`

Answer (score 2):

If you have heard something about "turning some values in enums on and off", then it must have been about flags enums. Which means, you can do the following:

```
[Flags]
public enum Coordinates
{
    None = 0;
    X = 1;  // binary 001
    Y = 2;  // binary 010
    Z = 4;  // binary 100
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
Coordinates enabledCoordinates = Coordinates.X | Coordinates.Y; // binary 011
Console.WriteLine(enabledCoordinates); // displays: X, Y (without Flags, it would display 3)
```

And then adding and removing can be performed by binary AND and OR operations:

```
// Adding Z coordinate: by binary OR
enabledCoordinates |= Coordinates.Z;

// Removing Z coordinate: by binary AND of the negated Z
enabledCoordinates &= ~Coordinates.Z;
```

Checking if a coordinate is added can be performed by binary AND:

```
// checking if Z flag is set
if ((enabledCoordinates & Coordinates.Z) != Coordinates.None)
    Console.WriteLine("Z is turned on");
```